# API created using NodeJs, Express, and Ejs files crashes when trying to fetch data from database a second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been tasked to create an API that fetches data from a database and displays it using frontend. This is my first time being exposed to creating an API and have been struggling a bit. The database is called fitnessTracker, it comprises of 4 tables userfit, exercises, workout, and workoutExercises. For my API in visual studio I have the following 'main' files: server.js, routes.js, controller.js, queries.js, db.js, index.ejs (serving as the main template), exercises.ejs, and userfit.ejs
Currently my queries in queries.js yield results perfectly on my ejs file, however, in an attempt to do it the second time, the server crashes/stops.

To demonstrate, I have a query in queries.js that fetches exercises by ID, it is as follows:
`const getExerciseById = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id = $1";`
which is then exported.

In my controller.js file, I have the following code to facilitate the above query:

```
const getExerciseById = (req, res) => {
  const exercise_id = parseInt(req.params.exercise_id);
  pool.query(queries.getExerciseById, [exercise_id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.render('exercises', { exercises: results.rows });
  });
};
```

Which is then exported

In my routes.js file, I have the following routes, where the last route facilitates above query:

```
const express = require('express');
const controller = require('./controller');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", controller.getUsers);
router.get("/userfit/id/:user_id", controller.getUserById);
router.get("/userfit/username/:username", controller.getUsersByUsername);
router.get("/userfit/emails/:email", controller.getUsersByEmail);
router.get("/userfit/genders/:gender", controller.getUsersByGender);
router.get("/userfit/heights/:minHeight/:maxHeight", controller.getUsersByHeightRange);
router.get("/userfit/weights/:minWeight/:maxWeight", controller.getUsersByWeightRange);

router.get("/exercises", controller.getExercises);
router.get("/exercises/e_id/:exercise_id", controller.getExerciseById);
```

The router is then exported,

In my index.ejs file, I have the following code to faciliate and display results for the above query:

```
<li>
      <form id="exercises-id-form">
        <label for="exercise_id">Search Exercise By ID:</label>
        <input type="text" id="exercise_id" name="exercise_id">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </li>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#exercises-id-form').submit(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          const exercise_id = $('#exercise_id').val();
          window.location.href = `/api/v1/fitness_tracker/exercises/e_id/${exercise_id}`;
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Now whenever I land on my index.ejs file and enter a random ID for instance 1, it goes to the appropriate URL and displays result, I press the go back button and come back to index.ejs and try the ID for a second time, upon this the server closes with the following error:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (c:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\RESTAPI\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (c:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\RESTAPI\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (c:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\RESTAPI\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\Desktop\JS\RESTAPI\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 141,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: "unnamed portal parameter $1 = '...'",
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'numutils.c',
  line: '235',
  routine: 'pg_strtoint32'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Here is the exercises.ejs file for further reference:

```
<!-- exercises.ejs -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>FITNESS TRACKER API - Userfit</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #222222; color: white;">
  <h1 class="text-center">Fitness Tracker - Userfit</h1>
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Exercises ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Calories Burned</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% exercises.forEach((exercise) => { %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= exercise.exercise_id %></td>
          <td><%= exercise.exercise_name %></td>
          <td><%= exercise.exercise_description %></td>
          <td><%= exercise.exercise_category %></td>
          <td><%= exercise.calories_burned_per_minute %></td>
        </tr>
      <% }); %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back(); // This will take the user back to the previous page
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Not only does it crash upon trying to fetch exercise by ID but even upon a simple refresh after I go back to localhost:3000 again.
I am not sure what seems to be the issue, I have tried using AI, however, it cannot provide me with any viable help either. I have also checked if it goes to the appropriate url the second time and it does, I have also seen that it takes the appropriate exercise id as the parameter by studying the url. I would appreciate any help to fix this, I am a newbie to nodejs, api's.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on github https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2310 with the same error `invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"`. It seems `exercise_id` isn't a valid integer,

Thus you should maybe verify first that `parseInt` returns a valid integer, e.g. `Number.isInteger(exercise_id)`, and add the base parameter for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

You can also use promises and use `then` and `catch` to handle the errors, in order to figure out where the error occured.

```js
const getExerciseById = (req, res) => {
  const exercise_id = parseInt(req.params.exercise_id, 10);

  if (Number.isInteger(exercise_id)) {
    console.log('valid id', exercise_id);
    pool.query(queries.getExerciseById, [exercise_id])
      .then((results) => {
        res.render('exercises', { exercises: results.rows }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  } else {
    console.log('invalid id', exercise_id);
    /* send an error page if the id is not valid */
  }
};
```

I hope this helps